# Ubuntu Mate 18.04 sources.list

Tags: updates, repository, software-sources

I have Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on my computer:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get:

```
Ign:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

How can I fix this? I am not able to install programs from repository, nor to update to a new version of Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: No, I don't have ppa-purge and I can't install it using sudo apt-get install ppa-purge. Also, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/bionic-media produces similar error as in my post.

Comment: Your `sources.list` is wrong. Why did you add `old-releases` there? `bionic` is not an old release.

Comment: Hi, it did not work for me. After selecting the recommended steps in software-properties-gtk I've got a message "Failed to download repository information." with the following details: E:The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com....

Comment: OK. I fixed it!!! The problem was in my internet connection. There was a router that asked for credentials, eventually showing a message: "authentication required by archive.ubuntu.com:80 the site says:"NETGEAR wnr2000v3""